# Action Controller: Exception undefined method 'title'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I seem to be unable to link my event.rb database to my html page.html.erb page that I want them to be displayed upon.

Here is the error I am receiving 
undefined method `title'

This is the line it isn't liking

```
<p> <%= link_to 'events', event_path(Event.title) %></p>
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  validates_presence_of :title, :whyGo
  validates_length_of :whyGo, minimum: 20
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
  }

  def self.get_current_events(current_date)
    @cga_events = Event.all.select('title').from('events').distinct

    #Queries the database for events ranging between the two DateTimes  *Parameterized Query*   
    Event.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).limit(1)
  end
end
```

Relevant portion of page.html where I am trying to loop through the events

```
<%= @cga_events.each do |event_obj|  %>
  <p> <%= link_to 'events', event_path(Event.title) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Please! Use spaces for indentation instead of tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `title` on the class `Event`. You need to be calling it on an *instance* of an event, in your case you are storing these instances in the `event_obj` variable. So your link should be

```
<%= link_to 'events', event_path(event_obj.title) %>
```

By the way, I think you might have your `link_to` syntax mixed up a little. `event_path` should accept an instance of `Event` as an argument. The first argument is the link text. I think what you are shooting for is

```
<%= link_to event_obj.title, event_path(event_obj) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I had another question related to this.
Now when I click the link that should bring it to the corresponding event it says 
undefined method `title' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Event

 <%= @event.title %>

Comment: How do you figure out how it should be set? 
I have been looking around my coding, 

events_controller

def index
@events = Event.all 

etc

which lets me get to the Events page, but clicking on the links from there gives me an error that it title isn't defined.

Thanks